# Как убрать все вхождения подстроки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Нужно удалить из строки все подстроки << подстрока >>. Непонятно, как не удалить подстроки <<<< ... >>>>, <<<<<< ... >>>>>> и т.п.

Comment: Приведите пример. Я что-то не понимаю чего не хочется удалять.

Comment: Есть строка *<<*>>*, где * - это любая последовательность символов, не содержащая << и >>. Нужно удалить подстроку <<*>>, получив строку **, но не тронуть подстроку <<<<*>>>>.

Comment: как только я не пробовал сделать это с regex'ом, так у меня и не получилось. У кого нибудь получилось(если да выложите плиз)? Или тут только свой метод писать без regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

а я не шарю в csharp, но регэкспы везде одни, так что:

```
preg_match_all('/<<(.(?!<<))+>>/Us', $data, $out);
```

выберет только те строки, у которых внутри нет <<, т.е. так сказать строки нижнего уровня.

Comment: Ого, а регэкспы в дотнете точно поддерживают упреждающую?